# How to make list page with data is an array, not from database in easy admin?

Tags: symfony, filesystems, easyadmin

I would like create a page which has 3 functions: allow admin upload a file to AWS S3, list files was uploaded on S3 in list view and delete file on S3. List view has 4 column : file name, file path, uploaded at and delete button. Everything will be simple if I do step by step : create a table in DB to save file info -> create entity -> config entities in .yaml file -> write controller, template. But in my case, I'm **not allowed** to create table. I have to use a exist service class call `S3Loader` (it used FileSystem and flysystem-aws-s3-v3) to get files on S3 by method: `$this->s3Loader->getFileSystemInstance()->listContents($directory)`, and it return an array:

```
[
  0 => array:10 [
    "path" => "csv/book3.csv_fd6d27b3ed14cea2b0917fb73a0cde8b.txt"
    "dirname" => "csv"
    "basename" => "book3.csv_fd6d27b3ed14cea2b0917fb73a0cde8b.txt"
    "extension" => "txt"
    "filename" => "book3.csv_fd6d27b3ed14cea2b0917fb73a0cde8b"
    "timestamp" => 1614581254
    "size" => "15"
    "storageclass" => "STANDARD"
    "etag" => ""653a009ae19247fcc37cb36fc110f667""
    "type" => "file"
  ]
  1 => array:10 [
    "path" => "csv/import-data-sheet1.csv_ee86a99c1e9598729faf1fdc2abd32d6.txt"
    "dirname" => "csv"
    "basename" => "import-data-sheet1.csv_ee86a99c1e9598729faf1fdc2abd32d6.txt"
    "extension" => "txt"
    "filename" => "import-data-sheet1.csv_ee86a99c1e9598729faf1fdc2abd32d6"
    "timestamp" => 1614581220
    "size" => "66"
    "storageclass" => "STANDARD"
    "etag" => ""ba67e091e37323ad3d04a1d40d305bba""
    "type" => "file"
  ]
]
```

I cannot find solutions in easyadmin documentation. How can I map this array to entity properties and show them to list view. The page don't need pagination, search.

Comment: Do you use any special bundle to upload files ?

Comment: I used league/flysystem and league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 to upload file to AWS S3